# Using IParameterInspector.BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs) to abort a call

Tags: c#, wcf, behavior, inspector

I have a custom behavior in which I implement "IParameterInspector" to be able to use BeforeCall and AfterCall. I'm currently using these methods to make some verifications before the call execute on my WCF service.

Here's my Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SendReceiveBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    public SendReceiveBehaviorAttribute()
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription desc, ServiceHostBase host)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher cDispatcher in host.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher eDispatcher in cDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                foreach (DispatchOperation op in eDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations)
                {
                    op.ParameterInspectors.Add(MyInspector);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
}
```

And my inspector:

```
internal class MyInspector: IParameterInspector
{
    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        // Make some verifications and cancel if it fails.

        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT
What would be the best way to abort my call if my verification fails?

Comment: Hi @Jean. BTW, did the other question sorted? I saw you marked it as answer I assumed it is fixed.

Comment: Also what is the question here?

Comment: Yes thank it worked. I was using IOperationInvoker and it didn't worked with your solution. So I've tried an IParameterInspector (the code above) and it works very well. Please look at my edit for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throwing exception is the only way - as far as I am aware - to abort.

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing, I'll wait a little bit so see if someone has a more official way to abort a call.